# Linux Ubuntu 20.04 does not detect external monitors (after installing KDE Plasma)

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, monitor

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday. And everything was fine with the monitors, and I wanted to install KDE Plasma. After that, the external monitor was not detected anymore.

I used the following commands to install KDE Plasma:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop
```

And during the configuration process, I сhose `sddm`.

Comment: If you want to use KDE, you should install Kubuntu which is the official flavor of Ubuntu that uses KDE.  Canonical publishes this and other official flavors with different desktop environments because it can be extremely messy to switch desktop environments on an installed system. It is definitely not a task for someone unfamiliar with manipulating the interworkings of the operating system. Since this is a fresh installation, your best path forward is probably to format (wipe) the disk and install Kubuntu cleanly

Comment: @Nmath Well, it looks like this user also followed procedures that made no mention of keeping different desktop environments on separate system installations. Sure hope NIGVUL has backup. This all points to a breakdown in simple communication between Canonical, DE developers and us Ubuntu users. I don't think that KDE (who have over the last 20 odd years done a lot of nice-looking work on DEs) will go into an involutional sulk if they are told to advise triers of their DE to do so on say a USB prior to making it their main system default DE . . .